# Identical observations in linear regression

Tags: regression, least-squares, singular-matrix

I want to do a linear regression $Y = X\beta + e$, but some of the observations (rows in $X$) are identical (about 30 000 out of 50 000 remain after deleting all duplicates), so when I try to calculate the OLS estimate $\hat{\beta} = (X^t X)^{-1} X^t Y$, the matrix $X^t X$ is singular. How do I remedy this?

Comment: Singularity in the row space should not be an issue.  Indeed, in the usual $n > p$ situation, there must of mathematical necessity be non-trivial vanishing linear combinations of the rows.  It is only in the column space that singularity is an issue.

Comment: Framed differently: Just because you have duplicate rows in $X$ does not imply that $X^tX$ is singular. Rather, that probably means that you have duplicate columns. How many columns do you have in $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add my comment as an answer, since it seems popular and I don't want to leave this unanswered:

> Singularity in the row space should not be an issue. Indeed, in the usual n>p situation, there must of mathematical necessity be non-trivial vanishing linear combinations of the rows. It is only in the column space that singularity is an issue.